# Reseting device list on Apple Developer account

Tags: apple-developer, apple-developer-account

[image]

I want to add a new device UDDID to the developer device list. It is showing the reset option.

- What will happen if I click the reset button?
- Will I lose all the devices connected to the list?
- Will this affect any apps or certificate or profile currently working?
- Do I have to add all the devices back manually?
- I am sharing IPA through diawi.com website, currently, the device
  connected to this account is working fine when I share an IPA. Will the reset affect this?
- How many deices can be removed at a time.

Answer (score 1):

No by resetting you can reselect the needed device.
it will show all available device and you can select which all device is needed. 
no issue for the certificates or provision profiles.